# Bearer token has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, apache, http, cors, http-options-method

i have trouble with cross origin access.
When i send a request without a bearer token in Authorization header, it's work.
When i do the same request with a bearer token, i have the following alert :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXX/API/TEST/TEST.php' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

In my php API i have the Following header :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Language,X-Authorization");
```

In my js script i have that :

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");   
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getCookie(COOKIE_NAME));
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

I have seen the folowing advice :

On the client, specify the Authorization header you want to include in the request.

On the server, respond with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, containing the origin that performs the request, or a wildcard.

On the server, respond with Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization to inform the browser that the Authorization header in the request is permitted.

But i can't get it work.

EDIT 1
I have found what was wrong :
When i use method PUT or DELETE it send a preflight request with "OPTIONS" as method type.
But my php code didn't allow OPTIONS, i add the following code after my headers and it's work fine !

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "OPTIONS"){
    http_response_code(200);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the preflight OPTIONS request which is causing the issue...does your PHP code definitely handle the OPTIONS request? It might depend on webserver config

Comment: @ADyson how can i chek that ?

Comment: That depends on what webserver you're running your PHP inside.

Comment: Unbuntu 21.04, Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks. In that case, [have a look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+options+request+php).